# @Autowired property in bean constructed as MVC method parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using the Spring MVC framework. In the code fragment below, is it possible for me to have Spring inject a bean into the `MyRequestClass` request parameter when it is constructed (ie. using `@Autowired` or `ApplicationContextAware` interface)? I need that request object to access one of my singleton Spring beans and would rather not have to create an `ApplicationContextAware` implementing singleton just for this purpose.

So far, I'm just getting NullPointerExceptions trying to access the beanaroo property with either approach.

```
@RequestMapping("/**")
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/mymethod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView myMethod(@RequestBody MyRequestClass request, 
                                   ModelMap modelMap,
                                   HttpServletResponse response) {
        ...
    }
}
```

eg.

```
public class MyRequestClass {

    @Autowired
    private MyInjectedBean beanaroo;

}
```

I also tried defining a prototype bean of that class in my application context file but it didn't have any effect either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, using `@Configurable` and aspectJ, but I wouldn't if I were you.

I'd just have the bean have a method that takes `MyInjectedBean` as param, and call that from the controller.

Comment: Good point... that's a simple enough solution. Don't know why that didn't occur to me in the first place! Thanks Bozho